# Problems with sorting (not a statement)

Tags: java, netbeans-7.4

The function is suposed to sort the highscore board in the game according to time.

```
public void sort()
{
    boolean unsorted = true;
    int i;

    for ( ; unsorted; i < this.inputArray.length - 1)
    {  
        unsorted = false;
        i = 0; continue;
        if (Integer.parseInt(this.inputArray[i][1]) <= Integer.parseInt(this.inputArray[(i + 1)][1]))
        {
            int tempTime = Integer.parseInt(this.inputArray[i][1]);
            String tempName = this.inputArray[i][0];
            this.inputArray[i][1] = this.inputArray[(i + 1)][1];
            this.inputArray[i][0] = this.inputArray[(i + 1)][0];
            this.inputArray[(i + 1)][1] = String.valueOf(tempTime);
            this.inputArray[(i + 1)][0] = String.valueOf(tempName);
            unsorted = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that IDE throws a "not a statement" error at 'for' loop, and "unreachable statement" error on 'if'.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think the problem is in the initialization of your 'for' loop.  I'm not a big java guy, but if you have a random semicolon in a C variant it can cause some issues.

Comment: I don't know what this is... but it's certainly wrong.  You'll never get to anything after `continue;` for starters.  And given the `for` loop's statements, it looks like a `while` loop would make this a whole lot more readable.

Comment: Take a look at the for statement tutorial and try to refactor: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: Exceptions are thrown. This is a compilation error. Compilation errors are printed, not thrown.

Answer (score 2):

The first error is because

```
i < this.inputArray.length - 1
```

is not something you can execute - that is, it's not a statement.  But the third part in the brackets of a `for` loop is the statement which will be executed at the end of each iteration of the loop.

The second error is because

```
continue;
```

means start the loop again, with the next iteration.  Which means that everything after the `continue` is dead code that can never be reached.  The compiler is trying to protect you from what can only be a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Unreachable Statement:
You assign i = 0, and then continue, and put i++ at the end, i will never be anything else than 0, so the if clause is unreachable

Your for loop syntax is incorrect as well:

```
for (initialization; termination;
     increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

- The initialization expression initializes the loop; it's executed once, as the loop begins.
- The termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
- The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop

(Taken from Oracle doc)